# TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor ошибка new Audio() в сафари

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, аудио, safari

Доброго времени, тестирую скрипт в сафари:

```
var audio = new Audio();

$(document).on("click", ".playaudeo", function () {
    audio.src = 'audio.mp3';
    audio.canPlayType('audio/mpeg; codecs="mp3"');
    audio.play();
});
```

в нормальных браузерах все работает но вот в сафари нет, а в консоли показывает такую ошибку:

TypeError: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Audio()')

скажите что не так? может надо заведомом создать пустой аудио тег и с ним производит операции?

Comment: Как на счет полного кода? а не просто js вырезку.

Comment: @NeedHate там просто див блок с классом playaudeo и собственно на него и надо нажимать что бы играла музыка)

Comment: какая версия сафари? для ios или для Mac?

Comment: @Grundy на ПК виндовс Safari 5/1/7

Comment: @dantelol, в пятой версии, скорее всего, это еще не поддерживается. Проверять надо на последних версиях, но для windows не получится, так как safari для windows больше не поддерживается

Comment: @Grundy прекрасные новости) а можно каким то образом не имея техники эппл тестировать сайты на нормальных устройствах?

Comment: @dantelol, можно посмотреть в сторону виртуалок с macos

Comment: тот же www.browserstack.com, услуга платная (после часового использовния), но как опция подойдет. Ну и какое-то "яблоко" тестовое все же лучше иметь.